# Mode among non-missing obs in past 3 days (not past three obs) in a panel data handling missing values in Python

Tags: python, panel, rolling-computation, mode

I have a panel of users tipping over time. Each observation is a single tipping transaction of a user i at date t. Users can have multiple tipping in a date and over time.

For each user at time t, I’d like to find the tip mode among any non-missing tip for that user during the past three days(don’t roll until finding three available but find the mode among the non-missing in past three days excluding the same day)

For example, If a user has 4 obs on date t, 3 obs in t-1, no obs in t-2, and 6 obs in t-3, the mode for each of those 4 obs on date t is equal to the mode among 9 observations during t-1:t-3. If she didn’t tip at all during t-1:t-3, set it equal to 0.

Below is the sample of my data and code. I'd like to create mode_3 but my code is not working properly.

I'd appreciate any help!
Thanks in advance!

```
userlink            date     tip   mode_3
/user/cmocmo    2008-09-21   1       0
/user/cmocmo    2008-09-22   NA      1
/user/cmocmo    2008-09-23   5       1 
/user/cmocmo    2008-09-23   5       1 
/user/cmocmo    2008-09-23   3       1 
/user/cmocmo    2008-09-23   NA      1 
/user/cmocmo    2008-09-24  .25      5
/user/cmocmo    2008-09-24  .25      5
/user/Azzarc    2008-09-24  .01      0
/user/Emsdad    2008-09-24  .25      0
/user/Emsdad    2008-09-25  .25      .25


data['mode_3']= data.groupby(['userlink'])['tip'].shift().rolling(window=3, min_periods =0).apply(lambda x: mode(x)[0])
```

Comment: Hello. In order for others to be able to help you with relevant answers, it is essential to share a reproducible sample of your date.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Anoushiravan. I added a sample of my data.

Comment: What is an obs? in the context of your problem?

Comment: Each observation is a single tipping transaction of a user i at date t. Users can have multiple tipping in a date and over time.

Comment: It is much better now. But the question sounds a little complicated. You can add more explanation.